# How to remove all services in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to remove all services I created in a Swarm:
[image]

To remove all the containers I used:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Is there a way to remove all the **service** with one line ?

I don't have a stack:
[image]
so `docker stack rm STACK_NAME` won't work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The same solution exists in services:

```
docker service rm $(docker service ls -q)
```

Comment: wow, Bret. was just doing the first swarm assignment (voting app) and here you are!!! You should add `docker network prune` here too.

Comment: These kind of solutions, kind of freaking me out.  Wouldnt it be easier to solve this command -->>   docker service rm all  -->> docker people think!

Answer (score 8):

You can just remore the stack

```
docker stack rm nameofstack
```

With this, all services will be removed.

To clean all volumes, containers, images and networks you can use:

```
docker system prune -a -f
```

Comment: You can have services without a stack, for example, in docker 1.12 where stacks are not available but services and swarm are.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one way to do it.

```
docker service rm $(docker service ls --format "{{.ID}}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way:

```
docker service ls | grep -v '^ID' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker service rm
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to remove a subset of services, say with a given name, use a [filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_ls/#filter):

```
docker service rm $(docker service ls -f name=your_service_name -q)
```